# Physics in Blender 3.3 Hair System?

Tags: physics, geometry-nodes, hair

I hear about all the great things about Blender's new hair system EXCEPT, for one thing, physics!

Can you add hair dynamics?? I am currently working on my first animation clip and held out for this update to create hair for my characters, and I plan to use Blender for the animation, thus I need to know if physics will work in this new system.

Comment: No, there is no physics like Hair Dynamics yet. Also, there are no settings for children, kinks, etc. You have to do this with Geometry Nodes at the moment. [It's planned to add these things in future versions of Blender](https://code.blender.org/2022/07/the-future-of-hair-grooming/).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything about this too... So far, the new hair system works good for nothing more than still renders unless you convert it into a particle system.

Answer (score 0):

you can rig it and even add cloth physic, all the required geonodes are in the Einar - hair grooming file. https://studio.blender.org/films/heist/gallery/?asset=6072

Weight painting them is a pain though.

first you need to generate a proxy mesh with the geonode and then you use the hair_deform