# How do I make Curlier hair using Blender 3.3?

Tags: hair

Am I increasing the wrong value?  I understand to get curlier hair, I must increase the number of segments.  However it's already at 25.  No matter what I do, I keep getting the same segments and I get very mechanical hair.  Which field should I be changing?  I'm using snake hook tool to make curls.

[image]

Comment: Is this the new hair curves of Blender 3.3 or the old particle hair system? Which setting is this on the bottom of the screenshot? (I recommend adding complete screenshots)

Comment: This is with Blender 3.3 the new hair system.  Adding another screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new *Hair Curves* (Blender 3.3) are fairly new and I guess there are not all user interface options implemented yet. They might be added in the future.

[image: hair curves]

Compared to the old *Hair Particle System*

1. there is no option for the smoothness of the curves like the *Hair Particle > Viewport > Strand Steps* setting
2. the selection color is missing in *Sculpt* mode
3. there is no option to make the control points visible
4. there is no *Rekey* menu entry to increase/decrease the number of control points

To increase the smoothness you need to increase the *Additional Subdivisions* value in the *Eevee Render Settings > Curves* section. Also, set *Curves* to `Strip`.

The thickness of the hair is controlled by the curve radius. Right now, the only way to set the radius is a *Geometry Nodes* modifier.

[image: smoothness and thickness]

With *Geometry Nodes* you also can modify the new curves and make the control points visible. Just add some nodes to the *Geometry Nodes* modifier which is called *Surface Deform* by default:

[image: geometry nodes for hair curves]

- the *Curve To Mesh* node solves issues (1) and (2)
- an *Instance on Point* node solves the issue (3) and
- a *Resample Curve* node works like the *Rekey* option mentioned in (4).

**Note:** Be careful, this could create lag in the viewport when you have a lot of hair.

Version 2 with a switch for the control points:
[image: visible control points v2]

Comment: Thanks for this.  What I want is for to curl each one of the hairs manually.  I'm not aiming for a full head of hair but just a few strands here and there but they'll all have different curls and thicknesses.

Is there a way I can do this manually?  There must be a way to increase the number of segments, it seems like such a basic function.  If not, why is it defaulted to 8??  and what do "points" represent on my screen shot?

Comment: Not to mention there doesn't seem to be a way I can change thickness.  But one step at a time...

Comment: Regarding smoothness and thickness, I have updated the answer above. There is a setting to make it look less blocky.  -- Maybe I don't understand your problem completely and you want to edit your question and add a sketch of your curly hair?
If you grab the tip of the hair with the *Snake Hook* brush and make a circular motion then you can create a curl. But if you continue and try to add more curls it will pull the previous curls back into a line. Is this the problem? The other control points can be moved with the *Comb* brush.

Comment: The *Points* setting in your screenshot is the number of control points. It's the cubes that you can see in the last two screenshots of my answer. I haven't checked yet but maybe you get a better result if you change the handle types or curve type with GN.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I don't know anything about geometry nodes in the moment so I can't comment further :(

Comment: Wait, so you're saying I can't make my hair thicker unless I use strips?  Is strips even hair?

Comment: Thanks, I think mine is working fine now. Though I don't understand how the node system works, I do know how to get what I want from what you showed me.

Comment: Can you animate hair by any chance or is it static?  If I want some wind blowing on it.

Comment: About the 'Strip' for the thickness: It always worked like this. Have a look  [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/210725/107598) -- In Blender 3.2(?), the Eevee render settings got renamed from 'Hair → Hair Shape Type' to 'Curves → Shape'. It is still needed to see the thickness of the hair in the viewport and Eevee. -- About physics: Something like Dynamic Hair is not available yet. You could use GN to make it wiggle a bit. Rigging and Cloth physics should be possible but I haven't tried. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274409/physics-in-blender-3-3-hair-system